# RecyclerView in XAMARIN VS2019 not displaying data in the designer

Tags: xml, visual-studio, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android, androidx

I was using a tutorial given through Microsoft Docs as a base for a RecyclerView to display reminders. I am new to Xamarin so I am not sure how simple this problem is, but although my code seems to be similar to the code presented by Microsoft, the designer does not display the data.

One key difference between my code and Microsoft's code is that theirs' uses v7 and mine uses AndroidX as v7 is now outdated. From what I can tell there are no real differences but I'm not 100 percent sure on that.

I want to add also that this is not being done in activity_main.xml and MainActivity.cs because this is not what I want to be displayed from the start. I am not sure if I am lacking something when it comes to connecting a specific layout file to a .cs file as all of my previous projects in Xamarin have been simple apps like a calculator with only one xml and one cs file.

This is the xml file that is supposed to display the recyclerView object, activityTwo.xml

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearlay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="273.0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="44dp"
        android:text="June 17th"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="95dp" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is activityTwo.cs, which has all the RecyclerView implementation.

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Views;
using AndroidX.AppCompat.App;
using AndroidX.RecyclerView.Widget;


namespace PlannerApp
{
    [Activity(Label = "activityTwo")]

    public class Reminder
    {
        public Reminder(string newName, string newDescription, string newStart, string newEnd, int newImage)
        {
            name = newName;
            description = newDescription;
            timeStart = newStart;
            timeEnd = newEnd;
            image = newImage;
        }

        public string name { get; }
        public string description { get; }
        public string timeStart { get; }
        public string timeEnd { get; }
        public int image { get; }
    }

    public class ReminderGroup
    {
        static Reminder[] exampleReminders =
        {
            new Reminder("Cardio Exercise", "Complete 20 minutes of Cardio", "12:00PM", "1:00PM", Resource.Drawable.Exercise),
            new Reminder("Posture Strecthes", "Complete 10 minutes of Posture-focused stretches", "1:00PM", "1:30PM", Resource.Drawable.health),
            new Reminder("LeetCode Problem", "Complete 1 hard LeetCode Problem", "1:30PM", "3:00PM", Resource.Drawable.Computer),
            new Reminder("Dentist Apointment", "Arrive on time for my apointment for 4:00", "3:00PM", "5:00PM", Resource.Drawable.apointment),
            new Reminder("Posture Strength Exercises", "Complete 10 minutes of Posture-focused strength training", "5:00PM", "5:30PM", Resource.Drawable.health),
            new Reminder("Play Breath of the Wild", "Complete 30 minutes of progress in Breath of the Wild", "5:30PM", "6:00PM", Resource.Drawable.Computer),
            new Reminder("Make Dinner", "Cook and eat a healthy dinner", "6:00PM", "6:30PM", Resource.Drawable.health),
            new Reminder("Play Minecraft", "Play with friends for 30 minutes", "6:30PM", "7:00PM", Resource.Drawable.Computer),
            new Reminder("Strength Training Workout", "Complete 20 minutes of Strength Training", "7:00PM", "7:30PM", Resource.Drawable.Exercise),
            new Reminder("App Development", "Complete 30 minutes of PlannerApp Development", "7:30PM", "8:00PM", Resource.Drawable.Computer),
            new Reminder("Watch Jojo", "Watch 4 episodes of Jojo", "8:00PM", "10:00PM", Resource.Drawable.Computer),
            new Reminder("Before Bed Routine", "Complete all lotion, teeth, and face care routines", "10:00PM", "11:00PM", Resource.Drawable.health)
        };

        private Reminder[] mReminders;

        public ReminderGroup()
        {
            mReminders = exampleReminders;
        }

        public int numReminders
        {
            get { return mReminders.Length; }
        }

        public Reminder this[int i]
        {
            get { return mReminders[i]; }
        }
    }

    public class ReminderGroupHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public ImageView Image { get; private set; }
        public TextView Title { get; private set; }
        public TextView Description { get; private set; }
        public TextView startTime { get; private set; }
        public TextView endTime { get; private set; }
        public ReminderGroupHolder(View itemView) : base(itemView)
        {
            Image = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView);
            Title = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewTitle);
            Description = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewDescription);
            startTime = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewStartTime);
            endTime = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewEndTime);
        }
    }

    public class ReminderGroupAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
    {
        public ReminderGroup mReminderGroup;

        public ReminderGroupAdapter(ReminderGroup reminderGroup)
        {
            mReminderGroup = reminderGroup;
        }

        public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            View itemholder = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.row, parent, false);
            ReminderGroupHolder vh = new ReminderGroupHolder(itemholder);
            return vh;
        }

        public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            ReminderGroupHolder vh = holder as ReminderGroupHolder;
            vh.Image.SetImageResource(mReminderGroup[position].image);
            vh.Title.Text = mReminderGroup[position].name;
            vh.Description.Text = mReminderGroup[position].description;
            vh.startTime.Text = mReminderGroup[position].timeStart;
            vh.endTime.Text = mReminderGroup[position].timeEnd;
        }

        public override int ItemCount
        {
            get { return mReminderGroup.numReminders; }
        }
    }

    public class activityTwo : Activity
    {

        RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
        ReminderGroupAdapter mAdapter;
        ReminderGroup mReminderGroup;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            mReminderGroup = new ReminderGroup();
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activityTwo);

            mRecyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerView);

            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

            mAdapter = new ReminderGroupAdapter(mReminderGroup);
            mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);


        }
    }
}
```

I don't think it is important, but just in case, here are the original mainActivity.cs and activity_main files. mainActivity doesn't really have anything but activity_main is meant to display a calendar.

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Views;
using AndroidX.AppCompat.App;
using AndroidX.RecyclerView.Widget;


namespace PlannerApp
{
    [Activity(Label = "Main", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]

    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);


        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/calGrid"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:rowCount = "9"
        android:columnCount="7">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text = "JUNE 2021"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="42dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_columnSpan="4"/>
        <TextView
            style = "@style/DOTW"
            android:text = "U"
            android:layout_column="0"/>

        <TextView
            style = "@style/DOTW"
            android:text = "M"
            android:layout_column="1"/>

        <TextView
            style = "@style/DOTW"
            android:text = "T"
            android:layout_column="2"/>

        <TextView
            style = "@style/DOTW"
            android:text = "W"
            android:layout_column="3"/>

        <TextView
            style = "@style/DOTW"
            android:text = "R"
            android:layout_column="4"/>

        <TextView
            style = "@style/DOTW"
            android:text = "F"
            android:layout_column="5"/>

        <TextView
            style = "@style/DOTW"
            android:text = "S"
            android:layout_column="6"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="0"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = ""
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="1"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = "1"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="2"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = "2"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="3"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = "3"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="4"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = "4"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="5"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = "5"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="6"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = "6"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="0"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = "7"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="1"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = "8"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="2"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = "9"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="3"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = "10"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="4"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = "11"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="5"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = "12"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="6"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = "13"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_column="0"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = "14"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_column="1"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = "15"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_column="2"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = "16"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_column="3"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = "17"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_column="4"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = "18"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_column="5"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = "19"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_column="6"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = "20"
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:layout_column="0"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = "21"
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:layout_column="1"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = "22"
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:layout_column="2"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = "23"
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:layout_column="3"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = "24"
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:layout_column="4"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = "25"
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:layout_column="5"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = "26"
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:layout_column="6"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = "27"
            android:layout_row="6"
            android:layout_column="0"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = "28"
            android:layout_row="6"
            android:layout_column="1"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = "29"
            android:layout_row="6"
            android:layout_column="2"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = "30"
            android:layout_row="6"
            android:layout_column="3"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = ""
            android:layout_row="6"
            android:layout_column="4"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = ""
            android:layout_row="6"
            android:layout_column="5"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = ""
            android:layout_row="6"
            android:layout_column="6"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = ""
            android:layout_row="7"
            android:layout_column="0"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = ""
            android:layout_row="7"
            android:layout_column="1"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = ""
            android:layout_row="7"
            android:layout_column="2"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = ""
            android:layout_row="7"
            android:layout_column="3"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = ""
            android:layout_row="7"
            android:layout_column="4"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = ""
            android:layout_row="7"
            android:layout_column="5"/>

        <Button
            style = "@style/Dates"
            android:text = ""
            android:layout_row="7"
            android:layout_column="6"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="8"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Upcoming:"/>

    </GridLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you!!

**EDIT:** This is my layout file, row.xml, with an example of what the format would look like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:src="@drawable/Exercise"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        
        
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
            <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

            <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text=":"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Start"
                android:id="@+id/textViewStartTime"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

            <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="-"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="End"
                android:id="@+id/textViewEndTime"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>
            />

            </LinearLayout>

         <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewDescription"
            android:text="Description"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px" 
            
            />
        
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

[A sample of the layout I am wanting for each individual item. Displayed with the row.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfHJa.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to use RecyclerView to displat some data, the layout manager calls OnCreateViewHolder when the RecyclerView needs a new view holder to represent an item. I find you don't create layout(ViewHolder) to display RecyclerView every item.

I follow your code do one sample, you can take a look:

Layout and Initialization

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView1"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>

public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    public RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    ReminderAdapter madapter;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        mRecyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerView1);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        madapter = new ReminderAdapter(ReminderNum.exampleReminders);

        // Register the item click handler (below) with the adapter:
        madapter.ItemClick += OnItemClick;

        // Plug the adapter into the RecyclerView:
        mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(madapter);
    }

    private void OnItemClick(object sender, int e)
    {
        int photoNum = e + 1;
        Toast.MakeText(this, "This is photo number " + photoNum, ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }

    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

View Holder

```
 public class ReminderViewHonder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public ImageView Image { get; private set; }
    public TextView txtname { get; private set; }
    public TextView txtdescription { get; private set; }
    public TextView txtstarttime { get; private set; }
    public TextView txtendtime { get; private set; }
    public ReminderViewHonder(View itemView, Action<int> listener)
       : base(itemView)
    {
        // Locate and cache view references:
        Image = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
        txtname = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
        txtdescription = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView2);
        txtstarttime = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView3);
        txtendtime = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView4);

        // Detect user clicks on the item view and report which item
        // was clicked (by layout position) to the listener:
        itemView.Click += (sender, e) => listener(base.LayoutPosition);
    }
}
```

Adapter

```
 public class ReminderAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter
{
    // Event handler for item clicks:
    public event EventHandler<int> ItemClick;

    // Underlying data set (a photo album):
    Reminder[] mReminderAlbum;

    public override int ItemCount
    {
        get { return mReminderAlbum.Length; }
    }

    public ReminderAdapter(Reminder[] ReminderAlbum)
    {
        mReminderAlbum = ReminderAlbum;
    }

    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        ReminderViewHonder vh = holder as ReminderViewHonder;

        // Set the ImageView and TextView in this ViewHolder's CardView 
        // from this position in the photo album:
        vh.Image.SetImageResource(mReminderAlbum[position].image);
        vh.txtname.Text = mReminderAlbum[position].name;
        vh.txtdescription.Text = mReminderAlbum[position].description;
        vh.txtstarttime.Text = mReminderAlbum[position].timeStart;
        vh.txtendtime.Text = mReminderAlbum[position].timeEnd;

    }

    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        // Inflate the CardView for the photo:
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).
                    Inflate(Resource.Layout.ReminderLayout, parent, false);

        // Create a ViewHolder to find and hold these view references, and 
        // register OnClick with the view holder:
        ReminderViewHonder vh = new ReminderViewHonder(itemView, OnClick);
        return vh;
    }

    private void OnClick(int obj)
    {
        if (ItemClick != null)
            ItemClick(this, obj);
    }
}
```

OnCreateViewHolder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <FrameLayout xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:padding="8dp">
<TextView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/textView1"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/textView2"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/textView3"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/textView4"/>
   <ImageView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"/>
 </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
 </FrameLayout>


 public class ReminderNum
{
 public   static Reminder[] exampleReminders =
   {
        new Reminder("Cardio Exercise", "Complete 20 minutes of Cardio", "12:00PM", "1:00PM", Resource.Drawable.internet),
        new Reminder("Posture Strecthes", "Complete 10 minutes of Posture-focused stretches", "1:00PM", "1:30PM",Resource.Drawable.internet ),
        new Reminder("LeetCode Problem", "Complete 1 hard LeetCode Problem", "1:30PM", "3:00PM", Resource.Drawable.internet),
        new Reminder("Dentist Apointment", "Arrive on time for my apointment for 4:00", "3:00PM", "5:00PM", Resource.Drawable.internet),
        new Reminder("Posture Strength Exercises", "Complete 10 minutes of Posture-focused strength training", "5:00PM", "5:30PM", Resource.Drawable.internet)
        //new Reminder("Play Breath of the Wild", "Complete 30 minutes of progress in Breath of the Wild", "5:30PM", "6:00PM", "Resource.Drawable.internet.png"),
        //new Reminder("Make Dinner", "Cook and eat a healthy dinner", "6:00PM", "6:30PM", "Resource.Drawable.internet.png"),
        //new Reminder("Play Minecraft", "Play with friends for 30 minutes", "6:30PM", "7:00PM", "Resource.Drawable.internet.png"),
        //new Reminder("Strength Training Workout", "Complete 20 minutes of Strength Training", "7:00PM", "7:30PM", "Resource.Drawable.internet.png"),
        //new Reminder("App Development", "Complete 30 minutes of PlannerApp Development", "7:30PM", "8:00PM", "Resource.Drawable.internet.png"),
        //new Reminder("Watch Jojo", "Watch 4 episodes of Jojo", "8:00PM", "10:00PM", "Resource.Drawable.internet.png"),
        //new Reminder("Before Bed Routine", "Complete all lotion, teeth, and face care routines", "10:00PM", "11:00PM", "Resource.Drawable.internet.png")
    };
}
```

The screenshot:

[image]

**Update:**

I download your sample to test, and find you don't set `MainLauncher = true` for activityTwo.cs, try to add the following code.

```
  [Activity(Label = "activityTwo", MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@style/AppTheme")]
public class activityTwo : AppCompatActivity
{
```

And delete  `MainLauncher = true` in Mainactivity.cs, because you just set one  `MainLauncher = true`

The screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I do have an xml made for the layout, I just forgot to add it, sorry about that. I will add it to the original post (along with a sample image of what it is supposed to look like). I tried using your layout though to see if something was wrong with mine, and it also did not show up in activity_two. Is it possible that it has something to do with me not using MainActivity.cs but another cs file, as I see you are using MainActivity in your example?

Comment: @xnautsing04 I think it is not related about Mainactivity.cs, are there some error message? If not, you can upload your sample at gtihub, I will download your sample to test.

Comment: There are no errors on my end. I uploaded it to github: https://github.com/xnautsing04/PlannerApp